# CSS flex property is not responding correctly when set to 0 from JS code

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

This might be a very simple oversight of something in my part, but so far I have a very simple project, that divides the screen into three parts, the first 2 parts are within a container with `display: flex`
and they are both given the same flex value of 1. In my JS code, when a specific boolean variable is set to false, I want one of those two parts to be hidden, and the other one to occupy its place.
This works as expected if I set 'flex: 0' in CSS, but not when I do it in JS.

```js
// Init on page load
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var gameContainer = document.getElementById("game-container");
    if (!false) { //this is to be changed later on to check for a boolean value
      gameContainer.style.flex = "0"; //this should hide the right part, but it does not
    }
});
```

```css
#whole-game {
  display: flex;
}

#story-container {
  background-color: black;
  height: 80vh;
  flex: 1;
}

#game-container {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 80vh;
  flex: 1;
}

#settings-container {
  background-color: rgb(83, 50, 8);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="whole-game">
    <div id="story-container"></div>

    <div id="game-container"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="settings-container"></div>
</body>
```

[This is how my screen looks on running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VduMN.png)

[This is how I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehoD7.png)

Comment: Is the result of the code execution wrong? Now it seems to be the same, as a link ("This is how I want it to look").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see on your code, you have declared the "gameManager" variable as array not object. So, if you want to execute the "trial" function, you need first to access the object index in the array, then the function:

```
var gameManager = [{
},

    {trial: function (){
        
      var gameContainer = document.getElementById("game-container");
      if(!false){ //this is to be changed later on to check for a boolean value
        gameContainer.style.flex = "0"; //this should hide the right part, but it does not
      }},
    
}]
// Init on page load
window.addEventListener("load", gameManager[1].trial);
```

Of course you gonna change index [1] to the actual index of the object.

Comment: Yeah, you are absolutely right, I am new to using JSON, and I was sure it was a silly mistake. Thanks a lot for the help, much appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it's because of the zero being a string?
Try making it `gameContainer.style.flex = 0;`